# $\phi: A\to A_S$ is an embedding for every multiplicatively closed set S $\implies$ A is integral

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, localization

Suppose $A$ is ring and $A_S$ denotes localized ring when $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$ containing $1$ and $\phi: A\to A_S$ is the canonical map $r\mapsto \frac{r}{1}$ where $\frac{a}{b}=$ equivalance class containing $(a,b)$. I was able to prove the following.

> $A$ is an integral domain $\implies$ $\phi$ is an embedding.

Proof: $\phi(x)=\phi(y)\implies\frac{x}{1}=\frac{y}{1}\implies\exists s\in S:s(x-y)=0$. By definition multiplicatively closed sets do not contain $0$ so $s\neq0$. As $A$ is an integral domain $x-y=0\implies x=y$. Therefore, $\phi$ is one-to-one.

But I'm unable to prove the converse. Is it true at all?

Comment: By "converse" do you mean "if $\phi$ is injective, then $A$ is integral domain"? This is not true.

Comment: Yes. But isn't it true according to Lord Shark's answer?

Comment: No. Consider a situation when the multiplicatively closed set contains only non-zero divisors. In this case also $s(x-y)=0 \Rightarrow x=y$, but $A$ need not integral domain. Can you think of an example?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife If $S$ is fixed the converse can be wrong as Krish let you know. If $S$ is *every* multiplicative set then the converse holds as you can see in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $s$ and $t$ are nonzero elements of $A$ with $st=0$. Consider $S=\{1,s,s^2,\ldots\}$. Then $t/1=0$ in $A_S$.

Comment: So $\phi(t)=\phi(0)$ and $\phi$ is not an embedding. So the converse is true. Did I follow it correctly?